# A javascript filter using a for/in loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to filter a javascript array? I've taken the following approach but it doesn't seem to produce the intended results.

**Arrays:**

```
var catalog1 = [0]
var catalog2 = [1]
var products = [{ id: "PRODUCTA", desc: "Toys" },
                { id: "PRODUCTB", desc: "Cars" }]
```

**Filter:**

```
var NewProducts = [];
for (r in catalog1) NewProducts.push(products[r]);
```

`NewProducts` should contain either product A or B depending on which catalog array is selected. My attempt always return product A, as in r = 0. What am I missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/rE52f/

Comment: In the code you've posted, you're always processing `catalog1`.

Comment: @TedHopp yes, I simplified it but in my code there a condition which sets the catalog. In the fiddle, you can see that if you use `catalog2`, it returns product A, not B.

Comment: `for (r in catalog1)` is not the correct way to iterate over an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because Javascript's for each loop generates the keys of your collection. You will have to change it to:

```
for (var r in someCatalogue) NewProducts.push(products[someCatalogue[r]]);
```

You can also use map inside a closure, if you don't have to support IE8 and less:

```
(function(products) {
  NewProducts = someCatalogue.map(function(item) { return products[item]; });
})(products);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to filter a JavaScript array, just use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var result = arr.filter(function(item) {
        return item > 3;
    }
);
```

In your situation you are trying to filter the `products` array to include certain elements, so to do it the right way:

```
var catalog1 = [0];
var catalog2 = [1];
var products = [{ id: "PRODUCTA", desc: "Toys" },
            { id: "PRODUCTB", desc: "Cars" }];

var NewProducts = products.filter( function(item) {
        // check item and if it is accepted then include it.
    }
);
```

In your code, you are using for/in to loop the array elements which is not the right way to walk the array, use a regular for loop:

```
var NewProducts = [];
for (var i=0; i<catalog1.length; i++) NewProducts.push(products[catalog1[i]]);
```